# How to filter custom segment in Google Analytics API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a segment created in Google Analytics, now I need for my API to return data with that segment. I have found some code in V3 but I am using V4 API, I have tried something like:

```
const requestObject = {
  resource: {
    reportRequests: [{
      viewId: VIEW_ID,
      dateRanges: [{
        startDate: START_DATE,
        endDate: END_DATE
      }],
      metrics: [{ "expression": "ga:pageviews" }, { "expression": "ga:bounceRate" }],
      dimensions: [{ "name": "ga:pagePath" }],
      dimensionFilterClauses: [
        {
          filters: [
            {
              "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath",
              "operator": "BEGINS_WITH",
              "expressions": filterExpression
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
                segments:[
                    {        
                        "segmentId":"gaid::segmentid"
                    }
                ]    
    }]
  }
```

but it gives me error.

Is there anyway to just add segment Id which I already defined?

I am getting error

> Error: Requests with segments must have ga:segment dimension.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I just put the segment name , which is not correct according to API . they ask to define all dimension filter etc

Comment: Error: Requests with segments must have ga:segment dimension. @kgrg

Comment: Have you seen this guide? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples#segments Seems to have an example to use segment by ID instead of building it dynamically: "segments":[    {      "segmentId": "gaid::-3"    }]

Comment: updated question                     segments:[
                        {        
                            "segmentId":"gaid::ahsu"
                        }
                    ]    @kgrg

Comment: Thanks for the updates, I hope the suggested answer will fix this error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is not totally clear, although it is suggesting how to fix it. You must include segment in your query as an additional dimension in your query. In your case it should look like this:

```
dimensions: [{ "name": "ga:segment" }, {"name": "ga:pagePath" }],
```